# Separate SessionStorage Vars in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

Currently, my session storage looks like:

[image]

My user id and level are showing on the same line. How could this be? I created to vars in my Angular loginService like so:

```
'use strict';
 app.factory('loginService',function($http, $location, sessionService){
return{
    login:function(data,scope){
        var $promise=$http.post('data/user.php',data); //send data to user.php
        $promise.then(function(msg){
            var uid=msg.data;
            var pass=msg.data;
            var level=msg.data;
            if(uid){
                //scope.msgtxt='Correct information';
                sessionService.set('uid',uid);
                //sessionService.set('lvl',level);
                $location.path('/home');
            } 
            if(level){
                sessionService.set('level',level);
                $location.path('/home');
            }
            else  {
                window.alert("Wrong credentials entered");
                scope.msgtxt='incorrect information';
                $location.path('/login');
            }                  
        });
    },
```

then in my login script, its simple - it checks against my rows and returns the value of level according to the users password and username entered.

```
$user=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));


 if(isset($user)) 
 {

        session_start();

        $useridname = $user->uid;
        $userpass = md5($user->pass);

        $_SESSION['uid']=$user->uid;

        //get level
        $sql = "SELECT lvl FROM dbo.users WHERE userid = '".$useridname."' 
           AND psw = ?";

        $params = array($userpass);
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql,$params);

      //if query does not work, return false
       if($stmt === false){
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
       }

           $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
           if($row)
           {
            do{
     //echo "You are being logged in... please wait!";
     //$_SESSION['lvl']=$user->level; 
          print $_SESSION['level'] = $row['lvl'];
          print $_SESSION['uid'];
```

For some odd reason, I can not for the life of me figure out how to get them to print separately on their own line. Without print, it won't print in the sessionStorage key and value fields. Can't figure this one out and ive been at it for a couple of hours now.

Any ideas from the Angular community?

**edited (data.php):**

```
$_SESSION['uid']=$user->uid;
$_SESSION['level']=$user->level;


//get userid and level from users table according to username and password entered
$sql = "SELECT lvl FROM dbo.users WHERE userid = '".$useridname."' AND psw = ?";
```

**edited (services.js):**

```
 login:function(data,scope){
var $promise=$http.post('data/user.php',data); //send data to user.php
    $promise.then(function(msg,lvl){
        var uid=msg.data;
        var pass=pass.data;
        var level=lvl.data;
           if(uid){
            //scope.msgtxt='Correct information';
            sessionService.set('uid',uid);
            sessionService.set('level',level);
            $location.path('/home');
        }
```

Comment: you set 3 variables with all the same values. `msg.data`

Comment: The way it is set up, msg.data retrieves all of the input values. Changing msg.data on my vars will cause them to not work.

Comment: well something sure isn't right, why would they all be set the same?

Comment: Are you saying to set them individually msg.data, pass.data, level.data? Pls advise @charlietfl

Comment: should be returning json not plain text from php

Comment: so i just set my vars as so msg.data, pass.data and lvl.data and no change in the way the Session is set. And yes, they are returning json. @charlietfl

Comment: not returning json if you have 2 print statements

Comment: Ok... so my uid is returning json but my level isnt. I made edits to the loginservice.js and data.php file which i placed above in my question... im now getting the error "$level" is not defined. But it is defined or atleast i thought i set it when i changed my data variables. @charlietfl

Comment: Undefined property: stdClass::$level (after my edits)